# How to hide specific tab when on different tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

What I am looking to accomplish is that when a user opens a modal I want it to display a date/time set by another party, however there is an option to "propose a new time" in the footer which the user can send a request to a the other user for a new time to meet. (See step 1 & 2 below for layout)

Step 1
[image: Step 1]

Step 2
[image: Step 2]

The question I have is what is the best approach to hiding specific options in the footer when "propose a new time" is selected? Is it best to use tabs to show the different content?

I've tried accomplishing this through tabs but was unable to hide specific tab options when on the "propose a new time" tab.

Expected results would be that when a user opens the modal the active content would display:

Step 1
[image: Step 1]

When a user selects "Propose a new time" it would then show them the following:

Step 2]
[image: Step 2]

Comment: Could you add some code showing what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jQuery on the site or pure js?

If you have jQuery loaded I'd suggest hiding the content you want hidden until the button is pressed. Then on click "propose new time" show the relevant content and hide other elements.

```
// First hide element
$('#hidden-on-load').hide();
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('#hidden-on-load').show();
    $('#content-to-hide').hide();
})
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what i was looking for. Thank you so much!